# Need to make 3 columns and i want to do it using Divs but isnt working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make 3 columns so that the three sections stay next to each other and not underneath each other. I am using Bootstrap but it seems to keep left aligning or centering underneath each other but not next to each other in columns.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <p class="section-subtitle wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="0.3s"></p>
</div>
<div class="section-header">
  <h2 class="section-title wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Services Offered</h2>
  <hr class="lines wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4, col-md-6">
      <div class="item-boxes wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="1.2s">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="advisory.html">Advisory and professional services</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4, col-md-6">
        <div class="item-boxes wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
          </div>
          <h4><a href="Pay.html">Payroll Outsourcing</a></h4>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4, col-md-6">
        <div class="item-boxes wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i>
          </div>
          <h4><a href="staff.html">Staffing Solutions</a></h4>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You'll also want to change your classes because having `md-4` and `md-6` on the same div are conflicting rules, and the 6 will override the 4 (because 6 is listed as the later class). But you can have different column widths if the breakpoint indicator is different: `col-md-4 col-lg-6`.

Comment: To clarify, is `md-6` listed later _in the CSS file_? Doesn't matter how it's listed in the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your classes to remove the commas. (I used `col-4` for demonstration purposes; you may want to use `col-md-4`. However, don't *also* use `col-md-6`. That doesn't make sense.)

Then, you were missing a closing div tag after the first column. A good editor will make that sort of thing more apparent.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <p class="section-subtitle wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="0.3s"></p>
</div>

<div class="section-header">
  <h2 class="section-title wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Services Offered</h2>
  <hr class="lines wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="item-boxes wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="1.2s">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="advisory.html">Advisory and professional services</a></h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="item-boxes wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="Pay.html">Payroll Outsourcing</a></h4>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="item-boxes wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="staff.html">Staffing Solutions</a></h4>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd also suggest that using heading elements for what's essentially a menu probably isn't appropriate. Element types shouldn't be used solely for styling. Instead, create custom menu classes or look at [Bootstrap's typography classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/typography/), which can emulate such styles without breaking semantic document structure.